# Calling same function multiple times gets me an error

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm programming in c#. I have written a method to generate random imei, which has 15 numbers from 0 to 9. I combine them using StringBuilder and return the whole code as string.

```
public static string randomIMEIgenerator()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (builder.Length < 15)
    {
        builder.Append(Rnd.Next(10).ToString());
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Now the thing is that I want to run this method x times, because I want to generate x imei codes. Why when I write for loop I get this error?

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

My main function:

```
private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();
int x = 5;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        randomIMEIgenerator();
    }
}
```

I also want to store all of those randomly generated imei's to an array. Should I just do it like that?

```
String[] array = new String[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    array = randomIMEIgenerator();
}
```

However my main question is about that error.

P.S. If I run this only one time, it generates one imei number. So the method randomIMEIgenerator is working properly.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Try making `x` static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'x' variable is called from a static method, so it should be static as well

```
 private static int x = 5;
```

For storing all of those imeis in an array, add the index in which you want to store the variable:

```
String[] array = new String[x]; 
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    array[i] = randomIMEIgenerator(); 
}
```

As a side note: you are **not** generating IMEI numbers. An imei number should end in a check digit, calculated with [Luhn Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks! Really useful information ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Fortega said, `int x` must be static if defined outside the main method.
I would also suggest to pass the RNG to the function as parameter instead of relying on a static variable.

To assign to the array, pass the correct array index.

```
String[] array = new String[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    array[i] = randomIMEIgenerator();
    //    ^
}
```

[C# fiddle for this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/taYWCT).